# Delete data from a table by fetching data from another table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have tried many R&D but this query could explain my question.
I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

```
select color_code from color_master WHERE color_code like CONCAT('%','(select color_code from artist_upload_painting where painting_stock_status = 1)','%')
```

I want to delete a row from master table whose color_code is in color_code field of table artist_upload_painting whose painting_stock_status = 1.

Comment: Why do i see two select?

Comment: Why don't use IN clause? `select color_code from color_master WHERE color_code IN (select color_code from artist_upload_painting where painting_stock_status = 1)`

Comment: because color_code in table color_master is like this "#182461" and color_code in table artist_upload_painting is like "#173a3c,#81876c,#b0b191,#405e5a,#565025,#7a9ca0,#4a3820,#66563e,#a3ac8c,".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use as below (subquery)

```
delete from color_master WHERE color_code  in (select color_code from artist_upload_painting where painting_stock_status = 1);
```

Comment: First of all i wanted to see if it returns some data or not. so i tried this code.
    select * 
FROM color_master 
WHERE color_code IN ( SELECT DISTINCT color_code
                     FROM artist_upload_painting
                     WHERE painting_stock_status = 1)

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem by myself. Here is the solution.

```
$del_Query = mysql_query("select DISTINCT(color_code) from artist_upload_painting where upload_painting_id = '$itemid'");
    while($Get_Result = mysql_fetch_array($del_Query))
    {
    $master_color = explode(",",$GetResult['color_code']);
    $uniq_color = array_unique($master_color);
        foreach ( $uniq_color as $color)
        {
            mysql_query("delete from color_master where color_code = $color");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DELETE 
FROM master 
WHERE color_code IN ( SELECT DISTINCT color_code
                     FROM artist_upload_painting
                     WHERE painting_upload_status = 1)
```

Comment: First of all i wanted to see if it returns some data or not. so i tried this code.
    select * 
FROM color_master 
WHERE color_code IN ( SELECT DISTINCT color_code
                     FROM artist_upload_painting
                     WHERE painting_stock_status = 1)

Comment: So is it returning anything or not?

Comment: No it is returning an empty set.

Comment: Do you have rows then with painting_upload_status = 1 in painting table and that color code in master table?

Comment: re-read my question painting_upload_staus is not a field. Its painting_stock_status.

Comment: "I want to delete a row from master table whose color_code is in color_code field of table artist_upload_painting whose **painting_upload_status = 1.**" Where have you specified painting_**stock**_status

Answer (score 0):

Join should be more efficient

```
DELETE FROM color_master 
JOIN artist_upload_painting
ON color_master.color_code = artist_upload_painting.color_code
AND artist_upload_painting.painting_stock_status = 1
```

If you run this query often you can add index in `artist_upload_painting` table on `color_code` and `painting_stock_status` columns to speedup this process.

Comment: can i see result using SELECT query before implement this code. so i tried this,
    select * FROM color_master 
JOIN artist_upload_painting
ON color_master.color_code = artist_upload_painting.color_code
AND artist_upload_painting.painting_stock_status = 1

Comment: When i used select this is returning an empty set.

Answer (score 0):

```
$queryToFindMatching = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM artist_upload_painting WHERE painting_upload_status = '1'");

while ($resultOfMatching = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryToFindMatching)){

    mysql_query("DELETE FROM color_master WHERE color_code = '{$resultOfMatching['color_code']}'");

}
```

Though, you really shouldn't use mysql_* functions.. Maybe consider the PDO or mysqli_* models and try to get into OOP.

Comment: What should i do if color_code in table color_master is like this "#182461" and color_code in table artist_upload_painting is like "#173a3c,#81876c,#b0b191,#405e5a,#565025,#7a9ca0,#4a3820,#66563e,#a3ac8c,".

Comment: "DELETE FROM color_master WHERE color_code LIKE '{$resultOfMatching['color_code']}'"

@Abhimanu

Comment: can i see result of this query using SELECT before DELETE?

Comment: "SELECT *  FROM color_master WHERE color_code LIKE '{$resultOfMatching['color_code']}'"

Comment: I have used this code in phpMyAdmin.
set @var = "SELECT * FROM artist_upload_painting WHERE painting_stock_status = '1'";
SELECT * FROM color_master WHERE color_code LIKE @var;

but this code return an empty set.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here. This code will only work with the given code segment that I provided in the initial answer i.e. It will only work in a PHP file when it's being parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELETE
FROM color_master CM
WHERE CM.color_code IN (
    SELECT AUP.color_code
    FROM artist_upload_painting AUP
    WHERE AUP.painting_stock_status = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Abhimanu

I have used this code in phpMyAdmin. set @var = "SELECT * FROM artist_upload_painting WHERE painting_stock_status = '1'"; SELECT * FROM color_master WHERE color_code LIKE @var; but this code return an empty set.

Please do this one.
@var = "SELECT ***** FROM artist_upload_painting WHERE painting_stock_status = '1'" instead of * use the particular column name which match the  color code

Comment: still this code is returning an empty set.
This Query return 1 result.
SELECT * FROM artist_upload_painting WHERE painting_stock_status = '1';

Comment: i am not getting why this query return an empty set please explain more data structure of  mysql and both query

Comment: The structure is : table artist_upload_painting had all the data of artist such that,(upload_painting_id is autoincrement and primary key, color_id[int], color_code[varchar], upload_painting_status[0 or 1], painting_stock_status[0 or 1]) and table color_master has two fields such that(color_id[int autoincrement], color_code [varchar]).

Comment: Now please check this one:
$colorcode = "SELECT color_code FROM artist_upload_painting WHERE painting_stock_status=1";
$colormasterarray="SELECT * FROM color_master WHERE color_code=".$colorcode;